# Dynamic programming problem: Optimal growth with linear utility

Tags: optimization, dynamic-programming

This is a question from Stokey-Lucas-Prescott "Recursive Methods in Economic Dynamics", question 5.3: Optimal Growth with Linear Utility. 
Q. Consider the following model-

(1) $\underset{x_{t+1}}{max} \sum_{t=0}^{\infty} \beta^t U[f(k_t) - k_{t+1}]$

st $0 \leq k_{t+1} \leq f(k^t), t=0,1,2 \dots$

given $k_0 \geq 0$

(2) $v(x) = \underset{0 \leq y \leq f(x)}{max} U[f(x) - y] + \beta v(y)$

We are given U(c) = c, so $U[f(k_t) - k_{t+1}] = f(k_t) - k_{t+1}$.

We are also given that:

(T1) f is continuous

(T2)f(0) = 0 and for some $\bar{x} >0: x \leq f(x) \leq \bar{x}$, all $0 \leq x \leq \bar{x}$ and $f(x) < x$, all $x > \bar{x}$

(T3) f is strictly increasing

(T4) f is weakly concave

(T5) f is continuously differentiable

b. Define $k* = \underset{k \geq 0}{max} [\beta f(k) - k]$. Show that for some $\epsilon > 0$, $|k - k*| < \epsilon$ implies $v(k) = f(k) - k* + \beta\frac{[f(k*) - k*]}{1-\beta}$

I'm stuck at part b. I've worked out that if I set up my $\hat{v}= \frac{f(k) - k}{1-\beta} $, then I can get $v* = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} T^n\hat{v}$. But I am having trouble theoretically explaining why $\hat{v}$ should be of this form for $|k - k*| < \epsilon$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you write question 5.3 so that we could know what it states and help you with your problem?

Comment: Hey. Definitely. The book is available online so I thought linking might help. But let me just put the question down.

Answer (score 1):

Resurrecting this old thread here since no one actually solved this problem and the solution isn't online. The idea behind the value function is that you want to start with a "guess" function and then use the Bellman Operator to iterate, figure out a pattern, and then figure out what the value function is.

In this case, the Bellman Operator on a function $g(x)$ would be given by:

$$T(g)(x) = \max_{y \in [0,f(x)]} f(x) - y + \beta g(y)$$

Usually you have a sup instead of a max, but since the feasible set is compact valued and everything is continuous, you can just use the max.

Now, think back to the problem. $k^*$ is such that it solves the equation $\beta f'(k) -1 = 0$ (as a critical point of the strictly concave function $\beta f(k) - k$), i.e. so $f'(k^*) = \frac{1}{\beta}$. Moreover, for $k$ substantially close to $k^*$, $f'(k) \approx \frac{1}{\beta}$. This is what the problem means for $|k-k^*| < \epsilon$. I think SLP don't necessarily want you to rigorously show what that $\epsilon$, the idea is that if you're close to $k^*$, the proper conditions hold.

The approach you should have to this problem is to start with a smart "guess" for the value function and then iterate. Look at the proposed value function $v(k) = f(k) - k^* + \frac{\beta}{1-\beta}(f(k^*) - k*)$. If you look at it long enough, you can come up with a pretty good guess for what the value function is. If you haven't figured it out what it is, check the spoiler below and I'll just tell you.

> Try the initial guess $g(x) = f(x) - k^*$. The first iteration under the Bellman operator $T$ will be: $$T(g)(x) = \max_{y \in [0,f(x)]} f(x) - y + \beta g (y) = \max_{y \in [0,f(x)]} f(x) - y + \beta (f(y) - k^*)$$ If you use calculus to maximize this function, you'll get the first derivative w.r.t $y$ to be $$- 1 + \beta f(y) = 0$$ Doesn't that look familiar? This is precisely the condition that gave us $k^*$, so the optimal choice of $y$ here is $y = k^*$. In turn, we have $$T(g)(x) = f(x) - k^* + \beta(f(k^*) - k^*)$$ Long story short, if you apply  $T$ again, you use the same trick and get $$T^2(g)(x) = f(x) - k^* + \beta(f(k^*) - k^*) + \beta^2(f(k^*) - k^*)$$ In general for $T^n$, you should get $$T^n(g)(x) = f(x) - k^* + \sum_{i=1}^n \beta^i(f(k^*) - k^*)$$ As $n \to \infty$, you'll converge to the value function $v(x)$, which is $$\lim_{n\to\infty} T^n(g)(x) = f(x) - k^* + \sum_{i=1}^\infty \beta^i(f(k^*) - k^*) = f(x) - k^* + \frac{\beta}{1-\beta}(f(k^*)-k^*)$$

Please excuse any typos and let me know if anything looks off!